# NodeJS & Firebase request query assembly

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

Good afternoon,
Im currently learning my way through NodeJS and have hit a problem I don't know how to solve. (I am pretty new to both Node and Firebase.)

I have a 'entries' collection in firebase that has entries that look like this:

```
{
    "id": "1zbRQwgo1uOGfjOZrtwO",
    "userId": "wCT1OU8xEkdPHHR4QFPN",
    "compId": "uH1Netp3kizZZaoBm57v",
    "roundId": 2,
    "scores": [
        7,
        7
    ],
    "total": 52
},
```

Initially i had a route for /entries/id/:id and a separate one for /entries/centreId/:id and another for /entries/userId/:id etc to allow my API to provide results based on ID or centreId or comp name. This works but is obviously not great and means a lot of duplicated code.

Im currently trying to move this to using "req.query" so I can have a single route that will handle things based on the query parameters being passed in the request.

I tried doing this with an If statement

```
 if (req.query['userId']){
        query = dbConn.db.collection('entries').where('userId', '==', req.query.userId) 

      } else {
        query = dbConn.db.collection('entries');

      };
```

Which sort of works but doesn't feel like that is the correct way to do things, if I want to search for multiple things eg. entries for a User ID AND a compID and possibly even a roundId at the same time it would just end up a mess of If blocks.

I thought Switch statements might be the way but that didn't work either.

What's the best way to do this so I send to firebase so I can end up with 1-x number of .where() sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore queries follow a builder pattern, which means you can build them up in multiple steps.

Typically that translates into something like:

```
// Start with a CollectionReference as our query
Query query = dbConn.db.collection('entries') 

// Handle each condition
if (req.query['userId']) {
    query = query.where('userId', '==', req.query.userId) 
}
if (req.query['name']) {
    query = query.where('name', '==', req.query.name) 
}
```

---

**If** each condition can be treated the same, you can also loop over all the keys in `req.query` instead of having repeated `if`s:

```
Query query = dbConn.db.collection('entries') 

Object.keys(req.query).forEach((key) {
    query = query.where(key, '==', req.query[key]);
});
```

In the above code, I just use `req.query` as that's what you shared. You might need to make sure the object you iterate over has only the query parameters.

Comment: Frank you are my hero of the day. Thank you for taking the time to explain that.